# std::max() and std::min() not constexpr

Tags: c++, max, c++11, min, constexpr

I just noticed that the new standard defines `min(a,b)` and `max(a,b)` **without** `constexpr`.

Examples from 25.4.7, [alg.min.max]:

```
template<class T> const T& min(const T& a, const T& b);
template<class T> T min(initializer_list<T> t);
```

Isn't this a pity? I would have liked to write

```
char data[ max(sizeof(A),sizeof(B)) ];
```

instead of

```
char data[ sizeof(A) > sizeof(B) ? sizeof(A) : sizeof(B) ];
char data[ MAX(sizeof(A),sizeof(B)) ]; // using a macro
```

Any reason why those **can not be `constexpr`**?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Critical Update

*The below analysis is wrong, because it confuses one important thing*. The following statement I did missed one important detail, which requires an entirely different answer.

> The unnamed reference `max` returns will refer to that operand.

The problem here is that *function invocation substitution* is **done** at that point. If the invocation susbstitution would include the lvalue to rvalue conversion on that glvalue that `max` yields, everything would be fine, because reading from a glvalue that refers to a temporary not of static storage duration is fine *during computation of the constant expression*. But since the read happens outside of function invocation substitution, the result of function invocation substitution is an *lvalue*. The respective text of the spec says

> A reference constant expression is an lvalue core constant expression that designates an object with static storage duration or a function.

But the reference that `max` returns yields an lvalue that designates an object of unspecified storage duration. Function invocation substitution is required to yield a *constant expression*, not merely a *core* constant expression. So `max(sizeof(A), sizeof(B))` is not guaranteed to work.

**The following (older) text needs to be read taking the above into account**.

---

I can't see any reason at the moment why you wouldn't want to stick a `constexpr` there. Anyway, the following code definitely is useful

```
template<typename T> constexpr
T const& max(T const& a, T const& b) {
  return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

Contrary to what other answers write, I think this is legal. Not all instantiations of `max` are required to be constexpr functions. The current n3242 says

> If the instantiated template specialization of a constexpr function template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr constructor, that specialization is not a constexpr function or constexpr constructor.

If you call the template, argument deduction will yield a function template specialization. Calling it will trigger *function invocation substitution*. Consider the following call

```
int a[max(sizeof(A), sizeof(B))];
```

It will first do an implicit conversion of the two `size_t` prvalues to the two reference parameters, binding both references to temporary objects storing their value. The result of this conversion is a *glvalue* for each case that refers to a temporary object (see 4p3). Now function invocation substitution takes those two glvalues and substitutes all occurences of `a` and `b` in the function body by those glvalues

```
return (<glval.a>) > (<glval.b>) ? (<glval.a>) : (<glval.b>);
```

The condition will require lvalue to rvalue conversions on these glvalues, which are allowed by 5.19p2

> - a glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile temporary object initialized with a constant expression

The conditional expression will yield a glvalue to either the first or second operand. The unnamed reference `max` returns will refer to that operand. And the final lvalue to rvalue conversion happening in the array dimension size specification will be valid by the same rule quoted above.

---

Note that `initializer_list` currently doesn't have `constexpr` member functions. This is a known limitation and will be handled post-C++0x, most likely making those members `constexpr`.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning, although I can not quite follow your "rvalue", "glvalue" magic. I saw those definitions in the std, but have to dig in there more deeply, I guess.

Comment: The C++ committee have suggested that it was intended to be possible for function invocation substitution to produce an lvalue referring to a temporary. g++ behaves that way, but clang currently implements the standard as written.

Answer (score 22):

std::min and std::max [are constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) in C++14, which obviously means there isn't a good reason (these days) not to have them constexpr. Problem solved :-)

Comment: This should have been comment I think

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion of `constexpr` versions of `std::min()` and `std::max()` in C++14 demonstrates that there's no fundamental obstacle to making (versions of) these functions `constexpr`.  It seems that this wasn't considered early enough when `constexpr` was added to C++11.

Obviously, for the versions where a comparison function is provided, that function must itself be `constexpr` for the template expansion to succeed.

Answer (score -1):

`min` and `max` are only constant expressions if you call them with constant expressions as arguments. Since they're meant to be much more generally usable than that, you can't make the declaration.

Here's what [Wikipedia says about `constexpr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Generalized_constant_expressions) (emphasis added). I know Wikipedia is not the ultimate reference, but I believe it's correct in this case.

> The use of `constexpr` on a function
>   imposes very strict limitations on
>   what that function can do. First, the
>   function must have a non-void return
>   type. Second, the function contents
>   must be of the form: return expr.
>   **Third, expr must be a constant
>   expression, after argument
>   substitution. This constant expression
>   may only call other functions defined
>   as constexpr, or it may use other
>   constant expression data variables.**

Comment: **after argument substitution** — `constexpr` does not disqualify variable arguments.

Comment: I sort-of disagree. The very straightforward implementation `T max(T a,T b) { return a>b ? a : b; }` *qualifies* to be declared `constexpr`. This declaration is independent from its *use*. If I *use* it with `constexpr` arguments, I could get a `constexpr` result.

Comment: Mark's answer is incorrect. At least in C++11, `min` and `max` are never constant-expressions, because they are not declared as `constexpr` in the standard library. But the OP asked: Why *aren't* they declared `constexpr`?

Comment: @Quuxplusone, my contention is that if a function is made `constexpr` then it must *always* be called with constant expressions as arguments. Do you disagree? Since `min` and `max` will almost always be called with non-constant arguments it would be impossible to make them `constexpr` which is why the standard did not make them so - that was my entire point.

Comment: @MarkRansom, yes, I disagree. `constexpr` essentially means "I can be constant", not "I must always be constant". (For the latter case, we already have `const` variables.) Try this in C++11: `constexpr int min(int a, int b) { return a<b ? a : b; }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char a[min(42,43)];
    static_assert(sizeof(a)==42, "test");
    printf("%d\n", min(argc,5));
}`

Comment: @Quuxplusone, you appear to be right, at least for gcc: http://ideone.com/PmYcA7 So what's the point of `constexpr` if the compiler is already smart enough to know if the result is constant or not? Is that just a gcc extension?

Comment: @MarkRansom http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-compile-time-processing-with-constexpr.html

Answer (score -3):

My guess is that, in the general case, operator<(T, T) is not guaranteed to be constexpr either.

Comment: So, it could be templated, with `constexpr` applying only to native operand types.