# C++11 constexpr to obsolete template meta-programming?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

As I understand it, `constexpr` is not Turing complete unlike template metaprogramming, so I believe these are not the same. So the question is to what extent does `constexpr` make template metaprogramming obsolete?

Comment: `constexpr` is Turing complete (ignoring the infinity requirements, obviously).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: If `constexpr` is Turing complete, please use only `constexpr` to model a list of integers growable in both ends.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: You may be interesting in posting that answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201506/is-constexpr-based-computation-turing-complete.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes The proof can be made much simpler. `constexpr` functions are trivially (?) [µ-recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function). QED. (Disregarding real-world restrictions, obviously.)

Comment: After some discussion in the chat I take that back. It might be feasible but it’s not trivial.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`constexpr` is absolutely Turing-complete. Recursion is allowed. It a convenient way to define functions that work at compile time as well as runtime. `constexpr` functions, being mere functions, cannot perform operations on types, though. (Unless you use template metaprogramming to define said function, of course.)

Both class templates and `constexpr` can be used to contain compile-time constant expressions, but there the similarity ends. They are not redundant and TMP won't be going away anytime soon.

Some particularly ugly compile-time calculations might be more elegantly rewritten as proper functions, though.