# Regex change all old cast style to static_cast style in c++ file

Tags: regex

I am a newbie in regex, I try to write a C# application that replace all of old cast style of c++ file to static_cast style.

For example:

```
(void)memcpy(&a[0],(void * )hihi, (UBYTE) V_SIZE);
(void) memcpy((VOID*)abc, (const VOID*) dafa, (uint8)NUMBER_SIZE);
(void )memcpy(
        (void *)p,
        &abc, (uint8)DATE_SIZE);
```

I expect all of them should be

```
static_cast<void>(memcpy(&a[0], static_cast<void * >(hihi), static_cast<UBYTE>( V_SIZE)));
static_cast<void> memcpy(static_cast<VOID*>(abc), static_cast<const VOID*> (hihi), static_cast<uint8>(NUMBER_SIZE));
static_cast<void >memcpy(
        static_cast<void *>(p),
        &abc, static_cast<uint8>(DATE_SIZE));
```

I also investigate and try with this one

```
List<string> castTypeList = new List<string>
{"void", "void *", "UBYTE", "uint8", "VOID*", "uint8" };

// Fix qacpp-4.7.0-3080 This expression uses old style casts
// Only apply for cpp source file (.cpp)
if ((Path.GetExtension(sourceFile) == ".cpp"))
{
    foreach (string e in castTypeList)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(sourceFile, Regex.Replace(
            File.ReadAllText(sourceFile),
            @"\(" + e + @"\)([^):;\r\n},]*)",
            "static_cast<" + e + @">($1)"));
    }
}
```

The result look good, but not perfect, some string can't match and replace (You can see below picture). Is there any better solution or better idea to handle it?
[image]

Comment: In your expected output the use of parentheses is not consistent, please revise.

Answer (score 0):

Reliably matching old-style casts is impossible with a regex, because you can't tell for sure what's a type and what's not. As proof, consider this C++ file:

```cpp
#include "somefile.h"

void f(sometype_t x) {
    g((something)*x);
    h((somethingelse)(x));
}
```

If `something` is a type, then the line with it is a cast, but if it's a variable, then it isn't. Similarly, if `somethingelse` is a type, then the line with it is a cast, but if it's a function, then it isn't. Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexer_hack

To really hammer the point home, consider this other C++ file:

```cpp
void g(long);
void h(char *);

template<int N>
struct SomeStruct {
    typedef int *sometype_t;
    typedef short something;
    typedef char *somethingelse;
};

template<>
struct SomeStruct<42> {
    typedef int sometype_t;
    short something;
    char *somethingelse(sometype_t);
};

constexpr int a = 12300 + 45;
constexpr int b = 40 + 2;

struct Child1 : SomeStruct<a> {
    void f(sometype_t x) {
        g((something)*x);
        h((somethingelse)(x));
    }
};

struct Child2 : SomeStruct<b> {
    void f(sometype_t x) {
        g((something)*x);
        h((somethingelse)(x));
    }
};
```

Now it should be clear that the only way to know whether or not those things are casts is by first evaluating arbitrary `constexpr` expressions, [which are Turing-complete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9528554/7509065).

Comment: yes, i think so, but is there anyway better to do it, i am not expect 100% perfect but 90-95% is fine, user need to check all changes again and fix by manual

Answer (score 0):

You can match and replace with the following pattern until no match is found:

```
(?i)\(\s*((?:const\s+)?(?:u?(?:byte|int)\d*|void)(?:\s*\*)?)\s*\)\s*(\w+(?:\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*\))?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uNQxR0/1).

In C#, you can use

```cs
var text = @"(void)memcpy(&a[0],(void * )hihi, (UBYTE) V_SIZE);\n(void) memcpy((VOID*)abc, (const VOID*) dafa, (uint8)NUMBER_SIZE);\n(void )memcpy(\n        (void *)p,\n        &abc, (uint8)DATE_SIZE)";
var pattern = @"(?i)\(\s*((?:const\s+)?(?:u?(?:byte|int)\d*|void)(?:\s*\*)?)\s*\)\s*(\w+(?:\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*\))?)";
var tmp = string.Empty;
do
{
    tmp = text;
    text = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "static_cast<$1>($2)");
}
while (text != tmp);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/2Q4n4A). Output:

```
static_cast<void>(memcpy(&a[0],static_cast<void *>(hihi), static_cast<UBYTE>(V_SIZE)));
static_cast<void>(memcpy(static_cast<VOID*>(abc), static_cast<const VOID*>(dafa), static_cast<uint8>(NUMBER_SIZE)));
static_cast<void>(memcpy(
        static_cast<void *>(p),
        &abc, static_cast<uint8>(DATE_SIZE)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution for myself.

```
List<string> part_one_CastTypeList = new List<string>
{"void", "void "};

List<string> part_two_CastTypeList = new List<string>
{"void * ", "UBYTE", "VOID*", "const VOID*", "uint8", "void *"};


if ((Path.GetExtension(sourceFile) == ".cpp"))
{
    foreach (string e in part_one_CastTypeList)
    {
        string castType = null;
        foreach (char c in e)
        {
            castType = castType + '[' + c + ']';
        }
        // Match multi pattern, variant is inside function (Applicable for void type)
        // i.e (void)memcpy((FLOAT)a, (void *) b, (uint8)c)
        // ==> static_cast<void>memcpy((FLOAT)a, (void *) b, (uint8)c)
        File.WriteAllText(sourceFile, Regex.Replace(
            File.ReadAllText(sourceFile),
            @"\(" + castType + @"\)([^;\r\n}]*)(\);)",
            "static_cast<" + e + @">($1)$2"));
    }
    foreach (string e in part_two_CastTypeList)
    {
        string castType = null;
        foreach(char c in e)
        {
            castType = castType + '[' + c + ']';
        }
        // Match single pattern, variant is not inside function (Not applicable for void type)
        // i.e (uint8)0x00,(uint16)0x01, (SW) 0x02
        // ==> static_cast<uint8>(0x00),static_cast<uint16>(0x01), static_cast<SW>(0x02),
        File.WriteAllText(sourceFile, Regex.Replace(
            File.ReadAllText(sourceFile),
            @"\(" + castType + @"\)([^:\/;)\r\n},]*)",
            "static_cast<" + e + @">($1)"));
    }
}
```

I will separate regex to 2 part. Part 1 (first for loop) will match the type cast of the function. After first for loop completed, all cast type of the function should be replaced like below

```
static_cast<void>(memcpy(&a[0],(void * )hihi, (UBYTE) V_SIZE));
static_cast<void>( memcpy((VOID*)abc, (const VOID*) dafa, (uint8)NUMBER_SIZE));
static_cast<void >(memcpy(
        (void *)p,
        &abc, (uint8)DATE_SIZE));
```

part 2 (second for loop) will match the type cast of the variant and replace all of the rest like below

```
static_cast<void>(memcpy(&a[0],static_cast<void * >(hihi), static_cast<UBYTE>( V_SIZE)));
static_cast<void>( memcpy(static_cast<VOID*>(abc), static_cast<const VOID*>( dafa), static_cast<uint8>(NUMBER_SIZE)));
static_cast<void >(memcpy(
        static_cast<void *>(p),
        &abc, static_cast<uint8>(DATE_SIZE)));
```

It's not perfect 100% but I try with many source files and it look good, it can match up to 99% :))