# When are "return-by-reference" or "pass-by-reference" parameter compatible with constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, constexpr

Functions marked constexpr are supposed to be immutable pure functions.  From the ["std::max() and std::min() not constexpr"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605142/stdmax-and-stdmin-not-constexpr) post, you can't re-channel a const-reference input as an output, since that would require the parameter to have permanence.  But can you take a parameter by `const`-reference, as long as you don't re-channel it?

```
// Is this still constexpr?
// (Assuming that std::complex is constexpr-safe, as it's supposed to be.)
constexpr
int  MySum( std::complex<double> const &a, std::complex<double> const &b )
{ return static_cast<int>( a.real() + b.real() ); }
```

Conversely, can you return a const-reference to a sub-object of a `constexpr`-enabled type?

```
template <typename T>
class MyComplex
{
    T  c_[ 2 ];
public:
    constexpr MyComplex( T r = T(), T i = T() )
    : c_{ r, i }
    {}

    // Is this actually constexpr?
    constexpr T const &  operator[]( unsigned l ) //const
    { return c_[ l ]; }

    // Can't be constexpr
    T &  operator[]( unsigned l )  { return c_[ l ]; }
};
```

Or do even sub-object returns have to be by value?

(Sorry if this is basic, but everything I've found dances around this point without actually being definitive.)

Answer (score 4):

The standard is pretty clear on what is allowed in a `constexpr` function:

`§7.1.5 [dcl.constexpr] p3`

> The definition of a `constexpr` function shall satisfy the following constraints:
>
> - [...]
> - its return type shall be a literal type;
> - each of its parameter types shall be a literal type;
> - [...]

`§3.9 [basic.types] p10`

> A type is a *literal type* if it is:
>
> - a scalar type; or
> - **a reference type;** or
> - a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties:
> - it has a trivial destructor,
>
>   - every constructor call and full-expression in the brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data
>       members (if any) is a constant expression (5.19),
>   - it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template
>       that is not a copy or move constructor, and
>   - it has all non-static data members and base classes of literal types; or
> - an array of literal type.

As such, yes, you can have reference parameters, even reference-to-non-const ones. The parameters of a `constexpr` function are restricted in another way. The complete, exhaustive list can be found under `§5.19 [expr.const] p2`. Here's an excerpt of what makes a `constexpr` declared function not-so-`constexpr` anymore:

> A *conditional-expression* is a *core constant expression* unless it involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression (3.2), but subexpressions of logical AND (5.14), logical OR (5.15), and conditional (5.16) operations that are not evaluated are not considered [ *Note:* An overloaded operator invokes a function. *—end note* ]:

(The last bit about the logical operators just means that the unevaluated part of it (due to short-circuit evaluation) is not part of the operations that determine whether the function is truly `constexpr`.)

> - [...]
> - a dynamic cast (5.2.7);
> - a `reinterpret_cast` (5.2.10);
> - a pseudo-destructor call (5.2.4);
> - increment or decrement operations (5.2.6, 5.3.2);
> - a typeid expression (5.2.8) whose operand is of a polymorphic class type;
> - a *new-expression* (5.3.4);
> - a *delete-expression* (5.3.5);
> - a subtraction (5.7) where both operands are pointers;
> - a relational (5.9) or equality (5.10) operator where the result is unspecified;
> - an assignment or a compound assignment (5.17); or
> - [...]

Comment: By that reading, `const T & std::min(const T &a, const T &b) { return !(b<a) : a : b ; }` should be `constexpr`able, but according to the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605142/stdmax-and-stdmin-not-constexpr, it shouldn't. So who's right?

Comment: @Marc: My answer doesn't contradict Johannes' answer. It's other language rules that make `constexpr` min/max functions that return references currently impossible, as rsmith's comment on the other answer notes.

Comment: ok, I bite the bullet: which one? You list a few, but none of them seem to ban taking or returning references.

Comment: @Marc: I think it's adequately laid out in Johannes' answer, and I can't formulate it any better. It's the second quote, also found in §5.19/3.

Answer (score 1):

[Core issue 1454](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1454)'s resolution changes the rule which Johannes is referencing in his answer to [the std::max question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605142/stdmax-and-stdmin-not-constexpr). With the current resolution of that issue (which is implemented by both g++ and clang), `constexpr` functions are allowed to return, by reference, any lvalue which they can compute.

Comment: Since this post, restrictions on `constexpr` functions have been even further relaxed (with the adoption of (your?) proposal [N3652](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3652.html)) for the upcoming C++14 standard. Nevertheless, in the current latest draft ([N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)), 25.4.7 [alg.min.max] `min` and `max` still aren't `constexpr`; is there a chance they will be "upgraded" before the final release?

Comment: @gx_ I don't think there's an NB comment on the C++14 draft requesting that `min` and `max` be made `constexpr`, and it's not in the LWG issues list, so it's unlikely to happen for C++14. Some members of the committee have been working on adding `constexpr` to all relevant library functions, so this should happen for C++17.