# Why is `constexpr` part of the C++14 template prototype for `std::max()`?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, constexpr

[Per cplusplus.com, here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/), the default C++11 prototype for `std::max()` is:

```
template <class T> 
const T& max(const T& a, const T& b);
```

In the C++14 version, however `constexpr` was added:

```
template <class T> 
constexpr const T& max(const T& a, const T& b);
```

Why is `constexpr` here and what does it add?

---

#### Note on possible duplicate

I think my question is not a duplicate of this one ([Difference between `constexpr` and `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const)), because I am asking about a very specific usage of `constexpr`, whereas that question is asking "tell me everything you know about const and constexpr". The specific usage is extremely hard to dig out of those massive answers because that other question isn't pointed enough and specific enough to drive the answers right to the point of my question.

### Related:

1. This info (this question plus what I learned from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434747/4561887) and others here) just went into my answer here: [MIN and MAX in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c/58532788#58532788)
2. [Difference between `constexpr` and `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const)
3. [std::max() and std::min() not constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605142/stdmax-and-stdmin-not-constexpr)

Comment: [std::max() and std::min() not constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605142/995714). And don't use cplusplus.com. It has been complained many times here due to lots of issues. See [What's wrong with cplusplus.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6520052/995714). https://en.cppreference.com/ is a much more reliable source

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between \`constexpr\` and \`const\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const)

Answer (score 3):

This means that the function can be used in constant expressions , for example:

```
constexpr int f = max(3, 4);
```

guarantees that `f` is evaluated at compile-time.

Note that a function marked `constexpr` may have both compile-time and run-time cases depending on the function arguments (and template parameters if it is a function template). It must have at least 1 compile-time case.

Since C++11 many standard library functions have had `constexpr` added .

Comment: It seems like you're contradicting yourself, no? **guarantees that f is evaluated at compile-time.** ... **may have both compile-time and run-time cases**

Comment: I don't see any contradiction here. It `guarantees that f is evaluated at compile-time.` because all inputs to f are `constexpr`. In other cases the function will be called at compile time

Comment: @GabrielStaples The guarantee is in that one specific example. The "may have" clause applies in all examples.

Comment: @GabrielStaples there will be a compilation error if `f` cannot be evaluated at compile-time

Comment: @M.M, only because the `int f` is declared `constexpr` no?

Comment: Got it; thanks. Upvoted now that I see it all. It's subtle. I recommend making it more obvious with a couple more sentences (the content of these comments basically)--so obvious _even I_ can understand it in a single go. That's a high bar.

Answer (score 2):

`constexpr` indicates to the compiler that the function's result can be calculated compile-time (given that the parameters also known at compile-time). I think this topic summarizes pretty well what you want to know:
[Difference between `constexpr` and `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const)

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some reading and it looks like it is a modifier in this case not on the return type, but rather, on the function itself. `constexpr` says that `max()` is a `constexpr` function. The `const T&` part says that the function returns a `const` reference to a type `T`, while the `constexpr` part, again, modifies the function itself.

This reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) indicates through its example that a `constexpr` function is a function which possibly can be evaluated at compile-time, but if not at compile-time, it will be evaluated at run-time like any other normal function.

Code snippet from the above reference (asterisks added):

```
constN<factorial(4)> out1; // computed at ***compile time***

volatile int k = 8; // disallow optimization using volatile
std::cout << k << "! = " << factorial(k) << '\n'; // computed at ***run time***
```

### Related:

1. This info just went into my answer here: [MIN and MAX in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437404/min-and-max-in-c/58532788#58532788)